# Loading resources in Cobalt HTML page

Tags: html, css, cobalt, npm-run

My question is 2 part.

**Part 1:** I am trying to build a simple HTML page using Cobalt using this: [Cobalt Support](https://cobalt.foo/development/reference/supported-features.html#html-elements)

My intention is to be able to create an application that allows for navigation between pages, loads external HTML components to index file and browse through those pages pretty smoothly. **Are these things possible with Cobalt? **

**Part 2:** If the above problems are solvable, **do cobalt support UI frameworks for easy workflow and development? **

Here is what I tried.

**Part 1:** I am unable to load any resource file on my HTML page which I created and hosted on a python server. The URL is accessible on browser and Cobalt loads the application using the same URL. Here is what I see.

1. Cannot load image files using  tag
2. Cannot load an external html file using  tags
3. Cannot see reference to these loaded files on Cobalt devTools

[devTools only shows index.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i2q3.png)

**Part 2:** I am trying to load a simple HTML page using npm dev run ( using vite ) for packaging. The page itself is nothing but a few tags that is supported by Cobalt, a CSS and a JS file. Cobalt can load these files by loading a HTML file using file:/// but does not support loading the same files hosted by a vite server.